# Jumping between changed lines in VIM with fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I have a huge file where I modified several lines, and saved it. The fugitive knows which lines are modified, and it would be very useful to just jump between them. Is there an existing hotkey for that, or can I map it somehow?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you mean you've done a `:Gdiff` to another revision or the index, you can use the built-in `]c` and `[c` motions to jump to the next / previous start of a change, as Vim shows the changes in `'diff'` mode.

Edit: Have a look at the [gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) plugin; it shows the changes in the sign column, updates those automatically, and even overloads the mentioned `]c` commands as you would like them to behave.

Comment: No, I didn't do a Gdiff; just an ordinary editing of file with git.

Comment: What do you then mean by "the fugitive knows"?! Does it really run a diff without `:Gdiff`?

Comment: It turns out I already installed `gitgutter`, but forgot about it, so I assumed that it was fugitive which was responsible for symbol column. Thanks for the link, it has this feature indeed!

Comment: Any way to get similar (jumping to changed lines) functionality with `:Gblame` ?

Answer (score 24):

Even without fugitive, vim maintains a changelist for every document which you can see by invoking `:changes`. You can jump through the changelist using `g;` (go to older change), `g,` (go to newer change).

Comment: This solution is too simple. ;-)

Comment: And it works with `:Gblame`, for which the accepted answer sadly doesn't.

Comment: Really usefull and this also works in VSCode with Vim plugin

Comment: not working. I thought the op is asking how to jump the changes in diff mode.